# Finding sum : ${\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\le i\lt j\lt k\lt l\le n }} \,1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Finding the value of: $${\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\le i\lt j\lt k\lt l\le n }} 1$$

I know a similar question was asked on this site earlier, but I couldn't understand the method used there.

[Link to similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521541/finding-the-value-of-mathop-sum-sum-sum-sum-0-le-i-lt-j-lt-k-lt-l-le-n?rq=1)

The answer of this question is $\binom{n+1}{4}$.

**My try:**

I tried tackling a smaller problem with two sums:

$$\mathop{\sum\sum}_{0\le i\lt j\le n } 1$$

I found that the inner sum was operated $n$ times then $n-1$ times then $n-2$ times ... so finally it was operated $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$ = $\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$ = $\binom{n+1}{2}$ times, which is the answer.

Using this approach **becomes very complicated** when higher number of summation signs are involved.

The general solution for $m$ summation signs seems to be $\binom{n+1}{m}$ though I do not know how to show!

Comment: In how many ways can you choose four distinct elements from the interval $[0,n]$? Can you see it is $\binom{n+1}{4}$? Can you see that your sum exactly accounts the ways for bla blah?

Comment: No answer wrote the explicit expression !!!. So, we have to believe the first satements !!!.

Comment: Where is this problem from? What's the source?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we use the formula
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{m}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}\tag{1}
$$
the method in the question is not all that cumbersome. Each sum building on the previous one, using $(1)$, we start with the sum for $1$ index:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{0}=\binom{n+1}{1}\tag{2}
$$
The sum for $2$ indices is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k+1}{1}=\binom{n+1}{2}\tag{3}
$$
The sum for $3$ indices is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k+1}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3}\tag{4}
$$
Finally, the sum for $4$ indices is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k+1}{3}=\binom{n+1}{4}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Sir for $3$ indices upper bound of sum will be $n-2$ or $n-1$ ?

Comment: @ankhmeteni: For sums $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$, the upper limit is $n-1$, and that is compounded for the higher sums, so that the smaller indexes are limited to $n-2$, $n-3$, etc.

Comment: @robjohn how are they limited? i am not doubting you i just can't see how it is limited by the top summation limit? by the bottom?

Comment: @transcenmental: Each sum is limited by the current variable in the next outer loop minus one because of the $\lt$ sign.

Answer (score 21):

This is just counting the $4$-element subsets of $\{0,1,,\ldots,n\}$.
There are $\binom{n+1}4$ of them.

Comment: Those 4 values actually stand for $i, j, k, l$! oh god am I blind!!