# Find the value of $\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\leq i<j<k<i\leq n} 2$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Find the value of $$\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\leq i<j<k<i\leq n} 2$$

Had it been $\displaystyle\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\leq i<j<k<l\leq n} 2$, it would be $2 {{n+1}\choose 4}$.

Is the question wrong? If not, please explain.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342139/finding-sum-mathop-sum-sum-sum-sum-0-le-i-lt-j-lt-k-lt-l-le-n-1/2342142

Comment: Just like your other (very similar) question, this is a straightforward consequence of stars and bars (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the value of $\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\leq i \leq j \leq k \leq l\leq n} 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493302/find-the-value-of-mathop-sum-sum-sum-sum-0-leq-i-leq-j-leq-k-leq-l-leq-n)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It's not a duplicate. In one case, I asked for the explanation of the question while in the other case, I asked for a solution using bijection of some form

Comment: Oh, okay. Coolios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost certainly a typo and your interpretation is correct. If it's not a typo then (a) the sum is equal to zero, since $0 \le i<j<k<i \le n$ is true for no values of $i$; and (b) there are four $\sum$ symbols but only three variables being (implicitly) summed over, which is somewhat unlikely.