# Find the value of $\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\leq i \leq j \leq k \leq l\leq n} 1$

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

Find the value of $$\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\leq i \leq j \leq k \leq l\leq n} 1$$

I am not sure but perhaps the answer is ${n+5}\choose 5$.

We know that $\displaystyle\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\leq i < j < k < l\leq n} 1
$ is ${n+1}\choose 4$. Can we do this problem from this fact using the [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%25E2%2580%2593exclusion_principle&ved=0ahUKEwio9PPlyJLXAhWMRY8KHe3nCXgQFgg1MAI&usg=AOvVaw2llcebaXgiTbXsl8nc67t8)?

Solutions using bijection would be quite elegant as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the number of quadruples $(i,j,k,l)$
with $0\le i\le j\le k\le l$. Let $(i',j',k',l')=(i+1,j+2,k+3,l+4)$.
Then the $(i',j',k',l')$ are the quadruples with
$0<i'<j'<k'<l'\le n+4$. How many of these are there?

Comment: We can re-write the same thing as: $0\leq i'' < j'' < k'' < l'' \leq n+3$ given that $x''=x'-1~ \forall x\in\{i,j,k,l\}$. And thus, our answer becomes ${n+4}\choose 4$. Now, for $n=0$, it works, right? It indeed is $1$ as $i=j=k=l=0$ and that's the only choice we have.

Comment: @Mathbg That's right!

Comment: Anyway, as I was trying, it's hard to do using Inclusion-Exclusion. There would be a lot of cases to consider individually.

Comment: @Mathbg: there is no need of inclusion-exclusion, this is just stars and bars (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) in disguise.